# Css Popup alert in button, instead input text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do i customize css so the popup alert just like this but instead alert popup focus in a button.
[image]

i have use this kind of validation on text box

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="judul_laporan">Judul Laporan </label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
         <input type="email" class="form-control" id="judul_laporan" >
     <span style="color: red" id="warnlaporan"></span>
    </div>
</div>

<button type="button" id="save_laporan"></button>
```

**JQuery**

```
 $("#save_laporan").click(function(){    
  var judul_laporan = $('input[name="judul_laporan"]'); 
  if(judul_laporan.val() == ''){
    judul_laporan.parent().parent().addClass('has-error');
    $('#warnlaporan').text("Judul Laporan Belum Ada");
    judul_laporan.focus();
    result
  }else{
    judul_laporan.parent().parent().removeClass('has-error');
     $('#warnlaporan').text("");
  }
```

But i dont know how to make a popup alert likes the image ( and it should be button )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the [x3schools'](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_popup.asp) documentation. It gives you a sample popup at the top of a div.

This code opens a popup:

```js
// When the user clicks on <div>, open the popup
function myFunction() {
    var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
    popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
```

```css
/* Popup container */
.popup {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* The actual popup (appears on top) */
.popup .popuptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 160px;
    background-color: #555;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 8px 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 125%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -80px;
}

/* Popup arrow */
.popup .popuptext::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -5px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

/* Toggle this class when clicking on the popup container (hide and show the popup) */
.popup .show {
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
    animation: fadeIn 1s
}

/* Add animation (fade in the popup) */
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
    from {opacity: 0;} 
    to {opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity:1 ;}
}
```

```html
<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()" style="left: 35px; top: 60px">Click me!
  <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">Popup text...</span>
</div>
```

---

You also can use [microtip](https://ghosh.github.io/microtip/), it is a pretty library witch give you the opportunity to create simply popup. This is the only declaration: `<button aria-label="Hey tooltip!" data-microtip-position="top-left" role="tooltip">`. However, you have to download a package (just 1kb) with rpm in your server.